# g++ link error: 'undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: c++, linker, g++, linker-errors

I have 3 files; main.cpp (which contains main()), FileWriter.h, and FileWriter.cpp. I'm using g++ (version Debian 4.9.2-10) on Debian Jessie. My project contains .cpp files in '/root/dev/Practice/src/', and a single header (FileWriter.h) in '/root/dev/Practice/include/'. The compilation of the two object files works, but the linking to an executable complains about undefined reference to main(), although I do indeed have a seemingly valid one defined in 'main.cpp'.

Here's the output of my make file (which is in the root '/root/dev/Practice/' directory):

> ```
> g++  -c -g -Wall  -o src/FileWriter.o src/FileWriter.cpp
> g++  -c -g -Wall  -o src/main.o src/FileWriter.cpp
> g++  src/FileWriter.o src/main.o -o bin/Practice
> /usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function '_start'"
> /build/glibc-J1NNmk/glibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/i386/start.S:111: undefined reference to 'main'
> collect2: error: ls returned 1 exit status
> Makefile:10: recipe for target 'bin/Practice' failed
> ```

Here's the contents of my main.cpp file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "/root/dev/Practice/include/FileWriter.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    FileWriter * fw = new FileWriter("foofile");
    fw->AddLine("CRAP!");
    fw->AddLine("NO!");
    return 0;
}
```

My FileWriter.h:

```
#ifndef FILEWRITER_H_
#define FILEWRITER_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class FileWriter{
public:
    FileWriter(std::string);
     ~FileWriter();

    void AddLine(std::string);

private:
    std::string fileLocation;
    std::ofstream  *filestream;
};

#endif /* FILEWRITER_H_ */
```

...and my FileWriter.cpp:

```
#include "/root/dev/Practice/include/FileWriter.h"
#include <fstream>

// g++ linker error if 'inline' not included - why?
inline FileWriter::FileWriter(std::string fileName)
{
    this->fileLocation = fileName;
    const char * x = this->fileLocation.c_str();
    this->filestream = new std::ofstream();
    this->filestream->open(x, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
}

inline FileWriter::~FileWriter()
{
    this->filestream->close();
}

inline void FileWriter::AddLine(std::string line)
{
    *this->filestream << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why the cursing? It can be frustrating but please refrain from doing so in public posts

Comment: @AndrewL he was preparing those words to say for when he realizes what the problem is...

Comment: Whoops! LOL sorry. Edited to remove that.

Comment: `#include "/root/..."`  . if you're compiling as root, you are a brave fellow :)

Comment: Brave, or just a dumb newbie who hasn't *yet* done anything to bad enough to make me create a user account :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
g++  -c -g -Wall  -o src/main.o src/FileWriter.cpp
```

should be:

```
g++  -c -g -Wall  -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
```

Comment: Why did I have a feeling it was that obvious? Thanks! However that leads to another 3 errors 'undefined reference to 'FileWriter::FileWriter..." for the 3 lines in main.cpp that reference my FileWriter class. Should I ask this separately?

Comment: @ErikJL: Those errors are due to the `inline`s in FileWriter.cpp, which mean those definitions are only visible to that compilation unit.  You need a non-inline definition somewhere, or an inline definition in a header included by `main.cpp`.

Comment: Thank you Chris - adding the 'inline' didn't feel right but it eliminated other compilation errors. Errors that likely now will be resolved with the other fix I hope.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to this compiler, but in the past if you had `main()` in a C++ file you needed to "decorate" it with `__cdecl`

```
int __cdecl main() {
```

Try that? Or:

```
extern "C" int main() {
```

Comment: syntastic complained about that change, it still compiled to main.o, however the linking still had the same error.

Comment: When all the source files are C++, and the C++ linker is used, none of these concerns would apply.  When you have to be careful is if `main()` is compiled with C compiler and also linked against C++ code